# Wordpress Website Url (permalink) Issue many duplicate url

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, yoast

I'm facing a issue in the my website showing the URL: something like 
https://www.example.com/90-degree-pallet-tippers-gallery/%22https:/www.example.com/wire/decking/flush-waterfall/%22https:/www.example.com/equipment/pallet-inverters/single-clamp-fs1900/%22https:/www.example.com/wire/decking/flush-waterfall-deckings/

There is lot of URL is similar to this. It means one page have many URLs following by the actual URL. 
https:/www.example.com/wire/decking/flush-waterfall-deckings/

Answer (score 0):

Go to your worpdpress admin and check the `Site Url` option there. If it looks correct, try disabling any newly installed plugins. If that doesn't help, you'll need to change the posts slugs in the database directly. You can do so in the `guid` field of `posts` table of your wp database.

Comment: my post slug is correct in database if i am checking orignal url it is fine but for same page there is 2 or 3 url i am using yoast plugin